# Is my sentence correct in this situation?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Suppose, I am cooking meal, and my daughter is doing homework.

Then my daughter asked me, "is the food ready?"

I answered: "it will be ready by the time you will complete your homework."

Is my answer is grammatically correct?
Tell me the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second instance of “will” and the sentence will sound correct:

> It will be ready by the time you complete your homework.

The part “you complete your homework” is in the subjunctive mood- you don’t know for sure that your daughter will complete her homework. Using the word “will” implies a certainty, but there is actually no certainty.

Comment: You can also say “by the time **that** you complete your homework”